# Exit button on phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

```
 function TT() {
                    switch (DevExpress.devices.real().platform) {
                        case "android":
                            navigator.app.exitApp();
                            break;
                        case "win":
                            window.close();
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

the code is not working on real iPhone (ios). The same code is work real phone android.
Not working means is There is no transaction. Why ?
ı use PhoneGap Cordova.
How to track a way?

Comment: Be informed that your app to Appstore might get rejected if you exit the app programatically. Although there exist an API in native iOS to quit, refrain from using it.

Comment: @Nirus How do I get out? I'm logging in with a password and then how will I get out

Comment: logout and throw the user to login screen. Its his wish to either be loggedin  or logout completely